# Mapstruct: Extract attribute to an object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct (1.2.0.Final) to map dto objects where I'd like to extract an attribute of an object to its own object instance.

Here is a simplified example:

```
@Data
public class ExternalResult {
    @JsonProperty("items")
    List<Item> items;
}
```

```
@Data
public class MyItem {
   String name;
}
```

Now I'd like to extract the `items` from `ExternalResult` and have them mapped to a list of `MyItems`. Here is my Mapper and I don't know what to use in as `target`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface GraphhopperMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "??", source="items")
    })
    List<MyItem> mapItems(ExternalResult externalResult);

}
```

How can this be achieved? Or is there a more convenient way to get rid of the (useless) object with only one attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use java [expressions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) in MapStruct and write the code to do the conversion, maybe there is an elegant enough way in java8 to keep it small and readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the cases where I'd recommend to just implement the method yourself (e.g. by making the mapper an abstract class) instead of trying to let MapStruct do it for you:

```
List<MyItem> mapItems(ExternalResult externalResult) {
    return externalResult.getItems()
        .stream()
        .map(i -> new MyItem(i.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

MapStruct idea is to help you automate the 90% of trivial mappings but let you hand-write the remaining more special cases like this.

Comment: If `MyItem` and `Item` are a bit more complex the map can even delegate to a MapStruct mapper between those 2 types

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. This worked for me. I implemented the method in an abstract mapper myself and used an abstract method from Mapstruct to to the rest of the magic: `return externalResult. getItems().stream().map(this::mapItem).collect(Collectors.toList());`